# I want to pass in constructor mode of file

Tags: c++, inheritance, file-handling

I created child class of ofstream. I want to pass in constructor mode of file. For example `ios::app`. How can i do it ? What should i write in `my_file` constructor to put it in `ofstream` class constructor? I know that it's `int` type but how to understand what is value of `ios::app`?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_file : public ofstream {
    string name;
public:
    my_file(string name, const char* filename) : ofstream(filename) { this->name = name; }
    inline const string get() { return this->name; }
};

int main(void) {
    my_file file("Name","new.txt"  /* , ios::app  */   );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just pass it to the base class like you're doing with `filename`.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `std::oftsream` instead of simply using a member variable?

Comment: @MateGvenetadze: Don't be agressive like that, people can ask you questions to figure out precisely what you want and later give you an answer.

Comment: Yes but they are pressing the "down" arrow.

Comment: @MateGvenetadze: How do YOU know? It's not necessarily the same persons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know that it's int type but how to understand what is value of ios::app?*

Wrong, that's not a `int`!

Go to `ofstream` doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/, then click [(constructor)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) to see what the parameters are and then you can see that mode is of type `std::ios_base::openmode` (as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/))

So simply do:

```
class my_file : public ofstream {
    string name;
public:
    my_file(string name, const char* filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode ) : ofstream(filename,mode) { this->name = name; }
    inline const string get() { return this->name; }
};
```

Then:

```
my_file file("Name","new.txt", ios::app);
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i wanted... But in constructor's description there is `int`  type. And i tried to write `my_file file("name","new.txt",(any integer number))` and it worked but i don't know it's definition. Where can i find it ?

Comment: @MateGvenetadze: Where have you seen any place where it's mentioned it's an int. I see no place like that in the doc. However, it's most likely implemented as an `int`, but passing an `int` may fire some warnings on some compilers. Just use `std::ios_base::openmode`, that's what the type is!

Comment: Like these: https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/23634642_407996486285669_130467435_n.png?oh=4c9daa04b64c815a556b3ad36d4acb8d&oe=5A0E7B8C

Comment: @MateGvenetadze: That's what your IDE thinks it is (this is not an official language reference), because it saw that `std::ios_base::openmode` is implemented as a `int` in the STL version you are using. However, I can' say if that will always be the case (when you'll change compiler, target...)